# MethodInfo, CreateDelegate and Generic Methods

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, methodinfo

Thanks to Jon Skeet's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307984/declare-a-generic-type-instance-dynamically) question I have the following working:

```
public delegate BaseItem GetItemDelegate(Guid itemID);

public static class Lists
{
  public static GetItemDelegate GetItemDelegateForType(Type derivedType)
  {
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Lists).GetMethod("GetItem");
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { derivedType });
    return (GetItemDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetItemDelegate), method);
  }

  public static T GetItem<T>(Guid itemID) where T : class { // returns an item of type T ... }
}

public class DerivedItem : BaseItem { }

// I can call it like so:
GetItemDelegate getItem = Lists.GetItemDelegateForType(typeof(DerivedItem));
DerivedItem myItem = getItem(someID); // this works great
```

When I try to apply the same thing to a method with a different return type and overloads (those are the only differences I can come up with), I get an annoying  "ArgumentException: Error binding to target method." on the call to `CreateDelegate`. The below is a working example that gets the error, just copy/paste into a console app.

```
public delegate IEnumerable<BaseItem> GetListDelegate();

public class BaseItem { }
public class DerivedItem : BaseItem { }

public static class Lists
{
  public static GetListDelegate GetListDelegateForType(Type itemType)
  {
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Lists).GetMethod("GetList", Type.EmptyTypes); // get the overload with no parameters
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { itemType });
    return (GetListDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetListDelegate), method);
  }

  // this is the one I want a delegate to, hence the Type.EmptyTypes above
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>() where T : class { return new List<T>(0); }
  // not the one I want a delegate to; included for illustration
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(int param) where T : class { return new List<T>(0); }

  public static Type GetItemType()
  { // this could return any type derived from BaseItem
    return typeof(DerivedItem);
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Type itemType = Lists.GetItemType();
    GetListDelegate getList = Lists.GetListDelegateForType(itemType);
    IEnumerable<BaseItem> myList = (IEnumerable<BaseItem>)getList();
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, the only differences I can see are:

1. Different return type (`T` works, `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't) *[EDIT: this isn't right, first version uses `BaseItem`, not `T`; oops]*
2. Overloads (`GetItem` has no overloads, `GetList` has several; I only need the delegate to `GetList()` with no params

**Update1:** Sam helped me pinpoint some issues. If the return type of the delegate is generic (e.g. `IEnumerable<BaseItem>`), it's choking when I try to swap base/derived types around. Is there any way I can declare my `GetList` method like below? I need to be able to indicate that `T` inherits from `BaseItem`, but if I could then it would work fine for me.

```
public static IEnumerable<BaseItem> GetList<T>() where T : class
```

The other option would be to "genericize" my delegate declaration. All examples I can find use a generic for the params, not the return type. How do I do this (it throws a compiler error cause `T` is undefined, and it won't let me use the `where` constraint):

```
public delegate IEnumerable<T> GetListDelegate();
```

Comment: In all the reading I did before posting this, I know type mismatch is one common cause for this exception. I set a breakpoint on the return calls in each example above, and the type of the variable method in each case seemed almost identical. I couldn't see anything amiss. Just thought I'd add that tidbit.

Comment: Why did this get changed to community wiki?

Comment: Wow, you edit your own post enough and it gets turned into a wiki automatically? That's damned stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten this working by declaring the delegate as just `IEnumerable`. This allows it to create the delegate. All that was remaining then was just basic casting. The below changes fix the second code block above.

```
// declare this as non-generic
public delegate IEnumerable GetListDelegate();
```

and

```
// do some cast-fu to get the list into a workable form
List<BaseItem> myList = getList().Cast<BaseItem>().ToList();
```

I can then do `myList.Sort()` and all the other stuff I am trying to do in my system at work.

Answer (score 1):

After making some minor modifications to get the second example to compile, I was able to run it and it gets and calls the delegate fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public delegate IEnumerable<BaseItem> GetListDelegate();

    public class BaseItem { }
    public class DerivedItem : BaseItem { }

    public static class Lists
    {
        public static GetListDelegate GetListDelegateForType(Type derivedType)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Lists).GetMethod("GetList", Type.EmptyTypes); // get the overload with no parameters
            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { derivedType });
            return (GetListDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetListDelegate), method); // *** this throws an exception ***
        }

        // this is the one I want a delegate to, hence the Type.EmptyTypes above
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>() where T : class
        {// returns a collection of T items ... 
            return new T[0];
        }

        // not the one I want a delegate to; included for illustration, maybe my different GetMethod() is my problem?
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(int param) where T : class
        { // returns a collection of T items ... 
            return new T[0];
        }
    }

    public class GenericDelegate
    {
        public static void Test()
        {

            // I would call it like so, but first line gets exception, where indicated above
            GetListDelegate getList = Lists.GetListDelegateForType(typeof(BaseItem));
            IEnumerable<BaseItem> myList = getList();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you got your second example to compile though.  There appears to be a problem here.

```
public delegate IEnumerable<BaseItem> GetListDelegate();

GetListDelegate getList = Lists.GetListDelegateForType(typeof(DerivedList));
IEnumerable<DerivedList> myList = getList();
```

The delegate is declared as returning IEnumerable but then you call it and assign the result to IEnumerable.  This isn't supported in C# 3.5.  It is in C# 4 but it would require declaring the BaseItem/DerivedList differently to declare covariance (or contravariance, I'm not sure which).

Comment: I extracted all this code from my large system at work and changed the type names and stuff to make a postable sample out of it. I should have made a sample app and played around with it first. Change the DerivedList type to DerivedItem. This was a copy/paste/replace error. I've edit my question to fix this. With that in mind, can you restate your last paragraph, because I'm not following you there.