# C#: Generic list of enum values

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Is there a way to create a method that gets an enum type as a parameter, and returns a generic list of the enum underlying type from it's values, no matter if the underlying type is int\short byte etc'...
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307984/declare-a-generic-type-instance-dynamically/308040#308040) of Jon Skeet, but it looks way too complicated.

Comment: Example input and output? i.e. do you want the list typed as `SomeEnum`, or as `byte` etc?

Comment: @MarcGravell as I wrote, I want the generic type to be of the underlying type - byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass in a `Type`, it can't really be usefully generic - you'd have to return a single type that **isn't directly related to the input**, hence something like:

```
    public static Array GetUnderlyingEnumValues(Type type)
    {
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(type);
        Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(underlyingType, values.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            arr.SetValue(values.GetValue(i), i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

This is a strongly-typed vector underneath, so you could cast that to `int[]` etc.

Comment: You can set the method to get the Enum type as a generic param, but it won't change a thing, right?

Comment: @gdoron indeed, have it `<TEnumType>` wouldn't help us, because we aren't returning `TEnumType[]`, but rather an `int[]`, `byte[]`, etc - which we can't tell via the generics.

Answer (score 2):

While Marc's answer isn't wrong its somewhat unnecessary. 
`Enum.GetValues(type)` returns a `TEnum[]` so this method is kind of unnecessary as if you know the underlying type you can just cast `TEnum[]` to its underlying type array.

```
var underlyingArray = (int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringComparison));
```

is valid C# that will compile and won't throw an exception at runtime. Since you wanted a list once you have the array you can pass it to the `List<Tunderlying>` constructor or you can just call the `ToArray()` extension method.

Edit: you could write the function as such::

```
public static TUnderlying[] GetValuesAs<TUnderlying>(type enumType)
{
     return Enum.GetValues(enumType) as TUnderlying[];
}
```

But then you would have to know the underlying type first.

Comment: Wow thanks! But still you can't return the strongly type list a function, right?

Comment: That's correct Enums are not generic types in the traditional way, if enums were generic like say `MyEnum: Enum<int>` then this would be possible.